# The phantom directive does not do what I expect

Tags: math-mode, phantom, latex-2-png

Typing these two codes on http://latex2png.com/:

```
\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}
```

and

```
\sqrt{a^2b}
```

I get the following results:

[image]       [image]

You will notice that the two square roots have different shapes and sizes, contrary to what one would expect from the description of `\phantom`.

Is there a workaround to achieve identical sizes?

Answer (score 21):

What goes wrong is that the argument of the square root is typeset in a *cramped* style.

If the radical appears in display style, then the material under the square root sign is typeset in *cramped display style*. However, `\phantom` only chooses among the uncramped styles, so you get a different height. In the following picture you see the output of `a^2` in uncramped and cramped styles

[image]

Clearly this explains the difference in placement of the radical sign you get.

Use `\cramped` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{a^2b}\,\sqrt{\phantom{\cramped{a^2}}b} \\
&\sqrt{\phantom{\cramped{a^2}}b}\,\sqrt{a^2b} \\
&\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use LuaLaTeX, then there's a slicker way: *redefining* `\mathpalette`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand*{\mathpalette}[2]{%
  \ifcase\mathstyle\relax
    #1\displaystyle{#2}\or
    #1\crampeddisplaystyle{#2}\or
    #1\textstyle{#2}\or
    #1\crampedtextstyle{#2}\or
    #1\scriptstyle{#2}\or
    #1\crampedscriptstyle{#2}\or
    #1\scriptscriptstyle{#2}\or
    #1\crampedscriptscriptstyle{#2}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{a^2b}\,\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b} \\
&\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}\,\sqrt{a^2b} \\
&\sqrt{\displaystyle a^2b}\,\sqrt{\displaystyle\phantom{a^2}b}\\
&\sqrt{\displaystyle\phantom{a^2}b}\,\sqrt{\displaystyle a^2b}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

***Caveat*** The above redefinition of `\mathpalette` doesn't guarantee success in all cases, particularly when a command defined with `\mathpalette` is used in a fraction. It's essentially a proof of concept.

Comment: I was sure you'd answer this question :):):)

Comment: why wouldn't an `\hphantom` work just as well?  maybe not in all cases, but in this case, ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd like to have a general solution.

Answer (score 8):

I don't use http://latex2png.com/, but, as jakun correctly pointed out, that seems to be so in display math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Inline:
    \(\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}\) 
    \(\sqrt{a^2b}\)

    Display style:
    \[\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}\] 
    \[\sqrt{a^2b}\]

    Display style whith \verb|\hphantom|:
    \[\sqrt{\hphantom{a^2}b}\] 
    \[\sqrt{a^2b}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It can be solved typing it in inline math:

```
$\sqrt{a^2b}$ and $\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}$
```

or using `\hphantom`:

```
\sqrt{a^2b}\sqrt{\hphantom{a^2}b}
```

this seems to give the correct output also on that site:

[image]

[image]

*Edit: reply to egreg's comment*

What about playing with `\hphantom` and `\vphantom` in that case?

I've added a grid to show that the dimensions seem correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[step=.1,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}}}
    Inline:

    \(\sqrt{a^{2^N}b}\)
    \(\sqrt{\hphantom{a^{2^N}}\vphantom{^N}b}\)

    \(\sqrt{\hphantom{a^{2^N}}\vphantom{^N}b}\)

    Display style:
    \[\sqrt{a^{2^N}b}\]

    Display style whith \verb|\hphantom| and \verb|\vphantom|:
    \[\sqrt{\hphantom{a^{2^N}}\vphantom{^N}b}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Type \sqrt{a^2b}\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b} into http://latex2png.com/

Comment: This might be an issue of display style vs inline math. When compiling `\begin{align} & \sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b} \\ & \sqrt{a^2b} \end{align}` with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) the root with the phantom is bigger.

Comment: @jakun That can be solved using `\hphantom`, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Wynne Look at my renewed answer according to jakun pointing out.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too simplistic: try `\sqrt{a^{2^N}b}` and then with `\sqrt{\hphantom{a^{2^N}}b}`

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what I'd recommend: it works for the specific case, but doesn't solve the general problem.

Comment: @egreg OK, it's a workaround :)

Answer (score 8):

Your example shows output from `\displaystyle`, i.e. between `$$...$$`. I'll explain **why** we can see such difference.

The `\phantom` macro creates a box like `\hbox{$\currentstyle contents $}`, empties such box but uses its dimensions.

It means that it does something like this:

```
$$ \sqrt{a^2 b}, \sqrt{\hbox{$\displaystyle a^2$}b}, \sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b} $$
```

[image]

Note that the exponent position is in another place in `\displaystyle` than in the argument of `\sqrt`, where reduced `\textstyle` is used. The position of exponents grows up in three steps: reduced textstyle, textstyle, displaystyle. The word "reduced" means that something is above such exponent, so exponent will be not high up. But when `\hbox{$\displaystyle a^2$}` is created then this is done independently of context and TeX does not know that there is something above the exponent.

Comment: +1. At the end of the first sentence, you wrote, "... where reduced `\textstyle` is used". Is it reduced (aka cramped) `\textstyle` that's in use here, or is it cramped `\displaystyle`? The difference between cramped `\textstyle` and cramped `\displaystyle`, AFAICT, is not in the vertical offset of the exponent "2" but, rather, in the amount of whitespace that's inserted between "2" and the horizontal bar of the square root symbol. Please advise.

Comment: The explanation is wrong. In the argument to the root, (cramped) display style is used, not text style, which you can see by trying `$$\sqrt{1\over2}$$\bye`.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, it appears that the output is correct in ConTeXt MkIV.

```
\starttext
\startformula
  \sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}
  \sqrt{a^2b}
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

gives

[image]

However, (as explained by @egreg below) the `\sqrt` in ConTeXt uses `\displaystyle` rather than `\crampeddisplaystyle`. If we switch to `crampeddisplaystype`, the output of `\phantom` is still correct:

```
\starttext
\startformula
  \sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}
  \sqrt{a^2b}
\stopformula
\startformula
  \sqrt{\crampeddisplaystyle\phantom{a^2}b}
  \sqrt{\crampeddisplaystyle a^2b}
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

I also tested with LuaLaTeX, but LuaLaTeX gives the same output as PDFLaTeX. Perhaps the ConTeXt definition of `\phantom` (defined in [supp-box.mkiv](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/supp-box.mkiv)) could be adapted in the LaTeX kernel or a LaTeX package.

Comment: It seems that ConTeXt is using the uncramped style under the square root, as the superscript is higher than with the cramped style.

Comment: It's possible through the `\mathstyle` int I imagine. In classic TeX may be just adding a `\insidesqrttrue` would help.

Comment: But the OP is using http://latex2png.com/ and if you put your MWE over there, it doesn't work

Comment: @egreg Tracing the code confirms this :)

Comment: @egreg, @JosephWright: Thanks. I added an example with the `\displaycrampedstyle` as well. I'll check if it is possible to change ConTeXt sqrt to cramped style.

Comment: @Aditya It's quite possible that `\phantom` in ConTeXt is able to distinguish among all eight styles.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, though the implementation in ConTeXt is simpler because one assumes that `\over` etc are never used (so there is no need for `\mathpallete` etc. See https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/supp-box.mkiv#L213